# AngularJs: multiple directives asking for isolated scope on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created two directives:

```
directivesModule.directive("capital", function () {
return {
    scope: {
        capital: "@"
    },
    link: function () {}
}
})

directivesModule.directive("country", function () {
return {
    scope: {
        country: "@"
    },
    link: function () {}
}
})
```

Next, I use them in the same element:

```
<div country="Russia" capital="Moscow"></div>
```

As a result, I get an error: `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [capital, country] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div country="Russia" capital="Moscow">`

How do I get the attribute values without scope?
These directives will not necessarily be used in conjunction.

Comment: Look here why you get this error http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile:multidir?p0=capital&p1=country&p2=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p3=%3Cdiv%20country%3D%22Russia%22%20capital%3D%22Moscow%22%3E

Comment: How do I get the attribute values ​​without scope?

Comment: You could use the `Attrs`(third) argument in your linking function and then `$eval` or `$parse` it against your scope in the function's body.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to your code, you don't need isolated scope to get attribute value. Just use this:

```
directivesModule.directive("capital", function ($parse) {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      // get attrs value
      attrs.capital

    }
}
})
```